# update database by form

Tags: php, html, function, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin page.php">
   <p>
     <label for="Name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="Age">Age </label>
     <input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="Email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
     <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" onclick="func();" />
   </p>
</form>

<?php 

 function func()
 {
  $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die(mysql_error());
  $db = mysql_select_db("lr") or die(mysql_error());
  $sql=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Persons (Name,age,Email,DOB)
                                       VALUES ('&Name', '&Age','&Email','&DOB')");
  if($sql){echo "Welcome ".$Name.",you may Login now! ";}

   mysql_close($con);    
 }

?>
</body>
```

This is my code i want to run my query on this very same page! I cannot do it on other page because i want to add users recursively in this page .I called function func on click to do that but its not working.

Comment: why do you always want to insert `'&Name', '&Age','&Email','&DOB'` it will be same for each user .. .and there is difference between & and $ i think you want to use $

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: Have you looked at your code. You are mixing all things altogether. You can't call `php` function onclick of button. For this you have to use ajax.

Comment: yes im new in php can you please help a bit ?

Comment: guide me with ajax please

Comment: @Asd try [php chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) , and you can also check this to know how to make ajax call with jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example/14217926#14217926

Comment: You mixing up mysql and mysqli

Comment: i am afraid but you really need to learn stuff from starting .. you are calling server side language function directly on client side without ajax something like that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

   $name= $_POST['Name'];
   $age= $_POST['Age'];
   $email= $_POST['Email'];
   $dob= $_POST['DOB'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ".
       "(name,age, email, dob) ".
       "VALUES('$name','$age','$email','$dob')";
mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
   <p>
     <label for="Name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="Age">Age </label>
     <input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="Email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
     <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add" />
   </p>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to **sql injection**  in `mysql_*` you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes I know . its just an example for the user . He can modify and can use mysqli or PDO if its available on server

Answer (score 2):

Try this corrections/changes in your code:

- action in form:
  `<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin page.php">` - no white-space between admin and page.php!
- `func()`. You cannot call php with onclick. Just remove that line `onclick="func();"`. The form submit action will do what you want. And remove also the `func() {}` and leave just the php
- INSERT: change `&` to `$` and concatenate your variables. For example I STRONGLY suggest you add also some validation for your form inputs to avoid sql injections.
- Getting the variables from the input fields: use `$Age = $_POST["Age"]` to get the variable from the form post.
- Your code is vulnerable to [**sql injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you just replace `&` to `$` in your query you need to properly escape all request in `mysql_*` you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [**`Mysql_*` api is deprecated**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) so either use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and imo use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)
- you are also mixing tow different api `mysqli_*` (`mysqli_query`) and `mysql_*` api which wont work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ajax like this :

```
//Submit form without refreshing page
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
        }
    });
```

Please refer [HERE](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html) and [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[DEMO](http://demos.9lessons.info/jqueryform.html)

Comment: please tell how this answer is helpful .... because its incomplete